# Why is Wordpress swapping double quotes (") to curly quotes (“) and how do I stop it from happening?

Tags: html, htmlspecialchars-decode

I have imported HTML into a Wordpress page, it contains some HTML as follows:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="bigger-image-path.jpg" title="<em>This is the image caption,</em> by someone">
 <picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 768px)" srcset="/image-path.jpg 1x, /image-path.jpg 2x"/>
  <img class="image-no-border" style="width:100%; height:auto" src="/image-path.jpg" alt="alt">
 </picture>
</a>
```

When I look at this HTML once it is imported via phpmyadmin, the HTML all looks correct as it is above.

But when I look at the page source, the HTML has been changed somehow to the following:

```
<a class="fancybox" href="bigger-image-path.jpg" title="<em>This is the image caption,</em> by someone”>
 <picture>
  <source media=" (min-width:="" 768px)"="" srcset="/image-path.jpg 1x, /image-path.jpg 2x" data-category="Open-popup" data-message="popupContent_bigger-image-path.jpg" data-type="popupType_hiddenDiv" data-fancybox-ready="true">
  <img class="image-no-border" style="width:100%; height:auto" src="/image-path.jpg" alt="alt">
```

Please note the curly quotes after the 'by someone' in the title="" attribute in the opening  tag.

After testing this only happens when the title="" in that opening  contains html tags, like the  tags it is currently containing.

This example isn't a one off, we have many examples of using html in the title="" tags of fancybox  tags, so I would like to understand why/how/where wordpress is making this change and a possible solution to stop it happening.

Comment: You can't use characters like `"`, `<` or `>` in HTML attributes. They need to be escaped. If a plugin or tool is allowing you to add HTML to attributes then that tool would be escaping those characters for you. If you're writing the HTML by hand you need to use `&gt;`, `&lt;` etc. in their place

Comment: When we import the HTML, it is creating a standard page. You can edit it in the basic page editor. And both in the page editor or the database the HTML looks correct, the double quotes at the the end of the title attribute are not curly. But when you view the source of the page in the browser, that is when the quotes have changed to curly.

I have tested escaping characters etc and actually importing curly quotes inside the title attribute and they appear curly in the database and page editor.

Wordpress is changing the HTML somewhere between the database and what it sends to the browser.

Comment: Yes, it’s changing it because your HTML is invalid. You need to escape those characters.

Comment: You are right! Thanks very much.